# Why document containing all search terms scored lower?

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf, elasticsearch-query

I am having search results with only 1 term to appear above the results matching two terms in the query. Below is my setup

**Search query**

POST index1/_search

```
{
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "content": {
                            "query": "devtools tutorial"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Settings and mapping used:**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Docs I have been using for testing purposes. I want doc with _id : 3 to appear above doc with _id:4 because it has both the terms in the query:

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "title" : "Introduction to elasticsearch", "content" : "Elasticsearch is a distributed, open source search slay and tutorial analytics engine for all types of data", "published_date" : "2020-01-02", "tags" : ["elasticsearch", "distributed", "storage" ], "no_of_likes" : 21, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "title" : "Why is Elasticsearch fast?", "content" : "It is able to achieve fast search responses because, instead small of tutorial searching the text directly, it searches an index instead", "tags" : ["elasticsearch", "fast", "index" ], "no_of_likes" : 10,"status" : "draft"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "title" : "Introducing the New React DevTools", "content" : "We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React  tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge", "published_date" : "2019-08-25", "tags" : ["react", "devtools" ], "no_of_likes" : 2, "status" : "published"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "4" } }
{ "title" : "Angular Tools for High Performance", "content" : "devtools", "published_date" : "2014-03-22", "tags" : ["angular", "performance","fast"], "no_of_likes" : 35, "status" : "published"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "5" } }
{ "title" : "The new features in Java 14", "content" : "Oracle on September 17 said switch expressions tutorial are expected naresh to go final in Java Development Kit 14 (JDK 14). ", "published_date" : "2019-07-20", "tags" : ["java"], "no_of_likes" : 11, "status" : "published"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "6" } }
{ "title" : "Thread behavior in the JVM", "content" : "Threading refers to the practice of executing programming tutorial processes accompani concurrently to improve application performance.", "tags" : ["java","jvm"], "no_of_likes" : 3, "status" : "draft"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "7" } }
{ "title" : "Stacks and Queues", "content" : "The main operations of a stack are push, pop, & isEmpty and for queue enqueue, dequeue, & isEmpty., ", "published_date" : "2016-12-12", "tags" : ["stack","queue","datastructures"], "no_of_likes" : 43, "status" : "published"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "8" } }
{ "title" : "How are big data and ai changing the business world?","content" : "Today’s businesses are ruled by data. Specifically, big data and AI that have gradually been murder  evolving to juvenile day-to-day business murder and playing as the key murder driver in business murder Intelligence decision-making","published_date" : "2020-01-01","tags" :["big data","ai"],"no_of_likes" :120,"status" : "published"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "9" } }
{ "title" : "Hash Tables", "content" : "A hash table is a data structure used to implement symbol table (associative array), a structure tutorial that can map keys to values", "published_date" : "2017-08-12", "tags" :[ "hash", "datastructures" ], "no_of_likes" :13, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "10" } }
{ "title" : "Go vs Python: How to choose", "content" : "Python and Go share a reputation for being convenient tutorial to work with. Both languages have a simple and straightforward syntax and a small and easily remembered feature set", "tags" :[ "go", "python" ], "no_of_likes" :134, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "11" } }
{ "title" : "Android Studio 4.0 backs native UI toolkit", "content" : "Now available in a preview juvenile, the weapon Android murder 4.0 ‘Canary’ upgrade works with the JetPack Compose UI toolkit and improves Java 8 support", "tags" :[ "android", "nativeui" ], "no_of_likes" :113, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "12" } }
{ "title" : "JSON tools you don’t want to miss", "content" : "Developers can choose from many great free and juvenile tools for tutorial JSON formatting, validating, editing, and converting to other formats", "published_date" : "2018-02-13", "tags" :[ "json" ], "no_of_likes" :23, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "13" } }
{ "title" : "Get started with method references in Java", "content" : "Use method references to simplify functional programming in Java", "tags" :[ "java", "references" ], "no_of_likes" :102, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "14" } }
{ "title" : "How to choose a database for your application", "content" : "From performance to programmability, the right childlike makes all the difference. Here are 12 key questions to help guide your selection", "published_date" : "2009-02-12", "tags" :[ "database" ], "no_of_likes" :229, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "15" } }
{ "title" : "10 reasons to Learn Scala Programming Language", "content" : "One of the questions my reader youthful tutorial ask me is, shall I learn Scala? Does Scala has a better future than Java, or why Java developer should learn Scala and so on", "published_date" : "2009-02-12", "tags" :[ "scala", "language" ], "no_of_likes" :136, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "16" } }
{ "title" : "ways to declare and initialize Two-dimensional (2D) String and Integer Array in Java", "content" : "Declaring a two-dimensional array is very interesting in Java as Java programming youthful provides many ways to declare a 2D array and each one of them has some special things to learn about", "published_date" : "2009-02-12", "tags" :[ "jaava", "datastructure", "array" ], "no_of_likes" :342, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "17" } }
{ "title" : "Hibernate Tip: How to customize the association mappings using a composite key", "content" : "Hibernate provides lots of mapping features that allow you to map complex domain and table models. But the availability of these features doesn't mean that you should use them in all of your applications", "tags" :[ "hibernate", "compositekey" ], "no_of_likes" :112, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "18" } }
{ "title" : "Getting started with Python on Spark", "content" : "At my current project I work a lot with Apache Spark juvenile running PySpark jobs on it.", "tags" :[ "python", "spark" ], "no_of_likes" :86, "status" : "draft" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "19" } }
{ "title" : "Relationship between IOT, big data, and cloud computing", "content" : "Big data analytics is the basis of decision making in an organization. It involves the examination of juvenile a large number of data sets in order to identify the hidden patterns that result in their existence.", "published_date" : "2018-11-10", "tags" :[ "iot", "big data", "cloud computing" ], "no_of_likes" :12, "status" : "published" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index1", "_id" : "20" } }
{ "title" : "Get started with juvenile expressions in Java", "content" : "Learn how to use lambda juvenile and tutorial functional programming techniques in your Java programs.", "tags" :[ "java", "lambda", "functional programming" ], "no_of_likes" :128, "status" : "draft" }
```

**Please note, doc-3 which has both `devtools` and `tutorial` scored lower than doc-4 which has just `devtools`.**

Comment: can you provide your mapping, sample docs and expected results, please provide the complete details so that its easy for us to reproduce your issue and provide your working solution

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I have editted the question and included the settings, mapping and sample docs

Comment: @Jam can you please share your `syn_test.txt` file also

Comment: @Bhavya updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent quite some time on this and found the root cause and solution of it, after analyzing the search output with `explain=true` param, if you notice, below is the formula to calculate the `tf` score

> **"description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl /
> avgdl))** from:",
>
> ```
> "details": [   {
> "value": 1.0,
> "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
> "details": [
>   
> ]   },   {
> "value": 1.2,
> "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
> "details": [
>   
> ]   },   {
> "value": 0.75,
> "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
> "details": [
>   
> ]   },   {
> "value": 2.0,
> "description": "dl, length of field",
> "details": [
>   
> ]   },   {
> "value": 29.545454,
> "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
> "details": [
>   
> ]   } ]
> ```

If you notice, its made of a total 5 component and `dl` ie length of field which matched the search result is very less in case of `doc-id` 4 as it contains just `devtools` and if you notice, this `dl` is part of the denominator and small value will increase the `tf` and final formula is `score(freq=4.0), computed as boost * idf * tf` if `tf` is multiplied with other components which are same for all the docs.

And this is happening due to [field normalization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html) and in order to fix it, you have to disable the `norms` on the searchable field and try again, I again defined the index-mapping with `norms` disabled on `content` field and got the results you wanted.

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And index docs using your `bulk` request and then use the same search request, which produce the below expected result:

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "64180913_1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 5.803219,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Introducing the New React DevTools",
                    "content": "We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge.We are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React  tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) EdgeWe are excited to announce a new release of accompany the React DevTools tutorial, available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge",
                    "published_date": "2019-08-25",
                    "tags": [
                        "react",
                        "devtools"
                    ],
                    "no_of_likes": 2,
                    "status": "published"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "64180913_1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 3.5244086,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Angular Tools for High Performance",
                    "content": "devtools", --> note this its below doc-3
                    "published_date": "2014-03-22",
                    "tags": [
                        "angular",
                        "performance",
                        "fast"
                    ],
                    "no_of_likes": 35,
                    "status": "published"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "64180913_1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.1478703,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Introduction to elasticsearch",
                    "content": "Elasticsearch is a distributed, open source search slay and tutorial analytics engine for all types of data",
                    "published_date": "2020-01-02",
                    "tags": [
                        "elasticsearch",
                        "distributed",
                        "storage"
                    ],
                    "no_of_likes": 21,
                    "status": "published"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "64180913_1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.1478703,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Why is Elasticsearch fast?",
                    "content": "It is able to achieve fast search responses because, instead small of tutorial searching the text directly, it searches an index instead",
                    "tags": [
                        "elasticsearch",
                        "fast",
                        "index"
                    ],
                    "no_of_likes": 10,
                    "status": "draft"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "64180913_1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 1.1478703,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "The new features in Java 14",
                    "content": "Oracle on September 17 said switch expressions tutorial are expected naresh to go final in Java Development Kit 14 (JDK 14). ",
                    "published_date": "2019-07-20",
                    "tags": [
                        "java"
                    ],
                    "no_of_likes": 11,
                    "status": "published"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**P.S: its nothing to do with `synonym` so I have removed that part to make your question short and simple.**

Comment: Try indexing all the docs. The result would appear otherwise. doc 4 would appear above doc 3. Also, my motive behind asking the question was to include the coordination factor in my query.

Comment: @Jam got it, now was able to repro the issue, please wait while I will edit my asnwer

Comment: @Jam, no need to spend more time on this and will get back when I have answer ready for it

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja there you go. I was actually looking for answers in the personal room.. Thanks for the answer. will go through

Comment: @Jam hi again, let me know if you found solution, looking frwd to hear from you

Comment: Hi, marked it as an answer. Thanks @OpsterElasticsearchNinja

Comment: @Jam, thanks and hope you found it useful :) and implemented it in suggested way